# Core Data model planning

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-design

Looks like I am stuck with decision of planning my Core Data model structure because I am not understand enough clear how Core Data need to work in my case. Now I have an entities `Customer` and `City` . Each with few properties in them and without relations between them now. They both have many relationships with other objects, so they are fully independent kind of objects. In my `Customer` entity I have `city` property (in what city customer is located). It's value needs to match to value of property `name` (name of the city)in `City` entity. Scheme looks like this: [image]

Objects to what `City` is an alias are formed by parsing JSON file from web and now this part works fine. I added a method in NSManagedObject subclass(generated from entity)for `Customer` to retrieve the name property value from `City` entity and store it in city property:

```
- (City *)city 
{
     return (City *)[[PTDataFetchHelper sharedInstance] entityForName:@"City" withServerID:self.city_server_id inContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
}
```

This works without relations, but my UITableView (I am using NSFetchedResultsController like source)start to work horribly slow with this kind of fetching. Also I understand that using this scheme I cannot implement search by both `Customer` and `City`objects - I can fetch only from one kind of entity. I found that I can create parent entity for this two, but they are logically and structurally independent. What is the best architectural way to solve this two problems?
Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

- You've made a deliberate effort to avoid setting up a relationship between `City` and `Customer` in the model.  I'm not sure why based on what I understand about your requirements.  You make the comment that you *"added a method in `NSManagedObject` subclass for `Customer` to retrieve the name property value from `City` and store it in `city` property."* but that's not what it seems you're doing.  You've created a getter method for the `city` property on `Customer` that dynamically fetches the city name from the context each time it is called. This may be the cause of the slowness you report.
- You **can** create an `NSFetchRequest` that traverses relationships.  Look into:

  - [KVC collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)
  - [Predicate format syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)
- `Customer` and `City` are not actually logically independent because `customerInstance.city` must always be a name that is a `cityInstance.name` as you have it structured now.

Comment: NSBum, you're absolutely right, no need to avoid relationships here. It's just the code I have from previous programmer and I need to fix it. Docs tell us that we can fetch much more than just only properties of one Entity, also everything from everywhere using relationships and predicates and this can solve my both problems. Thanks for help!

Comment: You might achieve a little better performance by having your `city` getter fetch the city name once from the `City` object if you want to keep the same architecture without relationships

Comment: I haven't necessity to keep untouched data model, so I will implement relationships between entities. Thanks again!